# Negative extra_requires in Python setup.py

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, setup.py, egg

I'd like to make a Python package that installs a dependency by default unless the user specially signals they do not want that.

Example:

```
 pip install package[no-django]
```

Does current pip and setup.py mechanism provide way to do this or does not need to have explicit `extra_requires` every time?

Comment: Closest I've found is this: https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins

Comment: @Rebs: your link is broken, I think the updated one is here http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins pardon me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Rebs that paragraph seems to have moved to the [Advertising Behavior](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins) section of Setuptools' documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. A way around it is to do a normal extra requires ... where

```
install_require=[
    # ...
    # no django listed here
],
extras_require={
    'django': ['django'],
}
```

and install with `package[django]` everywhere you need django installed.

Comment: Yeah it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. It doesn't use `extras_require`, but otherwise it satisfies all the stated requirements. With the bellow `setup.py` file, you can install as following:

```
# Regular installation
pip install package

# Installation without django
NODJANGO=1
pip install package
```

`setup.py` file:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

install_requires_without_django = [...]

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=install_requires_without_django  + ([] if os.getenv('NODJANGO', False) else ['django']),,
    ...
)
```