# Make pip install .[option] install less packages than the default pip install . (so-called negative extra_requires)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

First of all let's assume the following:

- I am building a python package `mypackage` and want to make it available broadly
- My package has the following python dependencies: "A","B","C" and "D" and we assume further that each dependency covers an independent use-case of the package (i.e. A is needed for users wanting to do A-type stuff, B is needed for B-type stuff, etc.)
- A, B, C and D are all pretty heavy and take each tons of times to install.
- The majority of the package's users are not developers and actually do not even know which type of stuff they will be interested in (whether it is one letter-stuff or any multiple letters simultaneously) and do not know how to do install with options
- Some users are power-users and know from the get-go that they will only use C and D-stuff so they will only need C or D as dependencies. In fact some of the non developer users might actually turn into power users given enough time to practice

From reading all hypotheses above then it makes perfect sense to have a default install installing A,B, C and D and having options available for power-users to install only C or D (or any package combination such as A and D).
Aka:

- `pip install mypackage` => installs A, B, C and D
- `pip install mypackage[C, D]` => installs C and D **but not A and B**

This exact same problem is stated in this other question under the name [negative extra_requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941264/negative-extra-requires-in-python-setup-py). Because indeed the desired behavior is that `extra_requires` should install fewer packages than the default install. It is also connected to discussions and issues in [several](https://discuss.python.org/t/possible-default-extras-dependency-categories/1537) [places](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1139).

I wanted to know 1. has the situation changed or is it planned ? 2. what would be a way to circumvent this issue/go about this if not?

Comment: It's being discussed (and has been for a while): https://discuss.python.org/t/adding-a-default-extra-require-environment/4898 -- No guarantee it will ever be standardized and implemented. -- In the meantime, I am from the camp that it is more than good enough to document things clearly and instruct your users (even the ones that are less comfortable) to do `python -m pip install 'mypackage[c, d]'`.

Comment: Hi @sinoroc thanks fo your comment ! I was aware I even linked it in my question. However this doesn't satisfy me entirely see because of pypy plus expected behavior from users (see comments below).

Comment: I linked a different, more recent discussion. -- If you think there is added complexity with PyPy, I think you should clarify it in the question, or rather open a new question.

Comment: I meant PyPi not PyPy my bad but you are right it's out of scope for this question but still I feel the answers I got were unsatisfactory so not accepting the answer. (Regarding the link you are right I got confused because I wanted to link this one and ended up linking to another one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. has the situation changed…?

No.

> or is it planned?

Nobody knows. Most probably no.

> 2. what would be a way to circumvent this issue…?

Do not install dependencies with plain `pip install mypackage`. Declare separate extras `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Declare a combined extra `all` that includes all dependencies:

```py
extras_require={
    'A': ['A'],
    'B': ['B'],
    'C': ['C'],
    'D': ['D'],
    'all': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
}
```

Document and teach your users to install the package using

```
pip install "mypackage[all]"
```

Teach your powerful users to install the package using

```
pip install "mypackage[A, C]"
```

or in any combination of dependencies they need.

Comment: Yes, good point for adding the quotes around `"mypackage[A, C]"`, because the square brackets can cause issues in some cases (in some shells).

Comment: Hi @phd thank you for your answer ! This is what I was doing (so I see that I was doing things right) but for instance it would break if I was to add it to PyPy no ? So it is a big limitation according to me. Additionally most non power users would not read the instructions and end up using pip install mypackage and not installing A, B, C and D.

Comment: This is not your responsibility if "non power users" do not read instructions. If I were you I would not think too much about this. This is the current state of the art in Python packaging, we are all in the same boat :) -- If you want to improve UX, then maybe your library could print out some clear warning messages at run-time on the console to explain that some dependencies are missing and how to install them.

Comment: @jeandut "*…it would break if I was to add it to PyPy…*" Why? PyPy uses the same `pip` and `setuptools`. What's wrong with PyPy?

Comment: I meant pip install mypackage would be the de facto command if it were to be published on pypy no ? But I guess this is a bit out of scope for this question. I understand your answers.

Comment: @jeandut Oh, I see — it's PyPI.org, not PyPy.org. PYthon Package Index, not PYthin in PYthon. :-)

Comment: Yes my bad I meant PyPi

Comment: @phd thank for your answer, I still think it is unsatisfactory so I am not accepting it but I upvoted.

Comment: @jeandut From my point of view this answer is the correct one. What you find unsatisfactory is the state of the art, not the answer.

Comment: You have a point it does answer the question however it is not very helpful. I accepted nonetheless.

Comment: @jeandut Unfortunately sometimes "No way" is the only answer, alas, deep sigh.